# The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 0x6 occurred while getting the console mode

Tags: powershell, azure

I currently have some problems with the azure commandline in a Web App.
I get following error:

```
[10/28/2015 20:22:33 > 37539e: ERR ] New-Item : The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 0x6 occurred while 
[10/28/2015 20:22:33 > 37539e: ERR ] getting the console mode. Contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.
```

This occurred on New-Item and Remove-Item. It happens in the Kudo Powershell console and using Powershell-Scripts ina WebJob.

Instead of `New-Item file` I have successfully used `echo 3 >> file`. This worked without problems. The only thing I found was that there is a problem using `Invoke-WebRequst` and that it will be fixed using

```
$ProgressPreference="SilentlyContinue"
```

Unfortunately this didn't helped.

Did someone experienced something similar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried to run these cmdlet remotely from your local computer?

Comment: no, I wasn't able to connect my local powershell to the WebbApp. Seems there is a problem because I use a Dreamspark subscription.

I run them in the Kudo Powershell and as WebJob.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 10):

Some cmdlets may attempt to read the console mode of the standard input or standard output streams if it is attached to the console. This can be avoided by setting them explicitly to null.

```
# Prevent the progress meter from trying to access the console mode
$ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

# Set the input and output streams to $null
$null | Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing http://www.example.com/ > $null
```

Comment: I see setting $ProgressPreference seems to be the agreed upon solution some time ago. It doesn't work for me still with it. Wonder if kudu behavior change recently. Anyone still seeing the issue ?

Answer (score 5):

For me, setting `$ProgressPreference="SilentlyContinue"` **does** solve the issue.
(Using the PowerShell Console of the Kudu site of an Azure App Service.)

`$null | (…) > $null` also prevents the error, but that also suppresses the return value, which I don't want.

Background: Apparently `Invoke-WebRequest` tries to display a progress bar, which Kudu's PowerShell does not support. ([source](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/8746375-set-powershell-progresspreference-to-silentlyconti))

Comment: Now the source link is not working if you can get it please post it +1 for guiding me to the solution to one of my commands